# Sicilian Classical

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 c5 
2. Nf3 d6
3. d4 cxd4 
4. Nxd4 Nf6 
5. Nc3 Nc6 
6. Be2 e6 
7. Be3 Be7 
8. O-O O-O
9. f4 Bd7 
10. Nxc6 Bxc6 
11. e5 dxe5 
12. fxe5 Nd7 
13. Bd4 Qa5 
14. Bd3 Bc5.
```

Questions.

1) Black played Sicilian Classical on move 5. What is the idea behind Sicilian Classical?

2) White is interested to play Be3 with the idea of protecting Nd4 and keeping an attack on b6 so that Queen can not come there. But Black may play ...Ng4 and attack Bishop on e3. So for this reason White plays Be2 first to avoid ...Ng4. Is this logic okay by White?

3) After 6 ... e6 White plays 7. Be3 keeping his previous logic in mind. Then after development both sides castle and White goes for 9. f4 attack with the idea of opening Rook file and controlling e5 square. Then White plays 10. Nxc6 and then 11. e5 to attack f6 Knight. So Black plays dxe5 and then White plays fxe5. Then Black plays ...Nd7 and attacks e5 pawn for which White plays 13. Bd4 to protect as well as keep an attack on long diagonal and kingside of Black. Then Black plays 13. Qa4 with further attack on e5 pawn. Then White played 14. Bd3 with the idea of 14. ... Nxe5 15. Bxh7+ Kxh7 16. Qh5+ Kg8 17. Qxe5 regaining the pawn. But Black played 14. Bc5 and further now White's kingside attack is slowly nullified by Black. Is e5 attack by White is logical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic to play Be2 to prevent Ng4 and to then play Be3 is sound. For the first 9 moves it looks very playable for white.

10.Nxc6 however is not a good idea. It activates the passive black bishop on d7 and is connected to the bad idea to play e5.

11.e5 is just a mistake as far as I can see. The pawn on e5 is too weak and you are bound to lose it. You could try to defend it with 13.Bf4, but in that case it seems to be possible to play Qb6+ and take on b2.

Look at [this game](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1482367) where 17 year old Magnus Carlsen slowly outplays World Champion Vishy Anand in a very similar setup. He does achieve a very strong attack and a winning position, even if he goes on to lose in the end.

Comment: Sir, Excellent!! By the way what is the main idea behind Sicilian Classical?

Comment: I don't think there is a single main idea that is specific to the classical Sicilian. For white, if he castles short, the main idea in Sicilians is usually to control space.

Comment: I liked the game you linked, it gave me a better idea of how to face the Sicilian in this line, not having studied theory for it. I thought Anands e5 push was very instructive, attacking the center in response to a wing attack. Still I'm surprised he did so well considering all the activity white had, seems like Carlsen goofed somewhere